# Navbar collapse on data-target does not collapse/expand on click

Tags: jquery, html, css, angular, twitter-bootstrap

I'm attempting to configure a navbar to collapse/expand on click of a data-target (hamburger icon).

When the view port is resized the navbar collapses, but it cannot be expanded to the contents of the navbar after collapse.

I have bootstrap installed as an npm package, but also referenced in the html to get it from maxcdn.

I have been using example 7 that can be found [here](https://www.codeply.com/go/qhaBrcWp3v).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <div class="d-flex flex-grow-1">
      <span class="w-100 d-lg-none d-block"><!-- hidden spacer to center brand on mobile --></span>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        LOIFF
      </a>
      <div class="w-100 text-right">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarToggle">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse  flex-grow-1 text-right" id="navbarToggle">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto flex-nowrap">
        <li class="nav-item" *ngIf="isUserAuthenticated()" [routerLinkActive]='["link-active"]' [routerLinkActiveOptions]='{ exact: true }'>
          <a class="nav-link text-white" [routerLink]='["/"]'>My Team</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</body>
</html>
```

I have used Angular 6 `*ngIf` expressions inside of some lists elements, I'm wondering does this cause the rendering to fail?

I've tried reordering the `<script>` tags, as I seen some in some other posts that the order of the tags can matter.

I've also tried placing the `script` tags inside of the body, instead of the header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Angular, don't use  Jquery/Bootstrap.js Angular has no control over that, Use Bootstrap css with [ngBootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home) . See this [Plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/plunk/xH6VJo) for Navbar or [Accordion](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/accordion/examples) etc.

Comment: Oh, ouch. I'm using ngx-bootstrap now. Starting over. Thank you!